# Add a link in last column of specific row, after last span, using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop-down for change state in each row of my table. This drop-down will change the state of current row by Ajax call. If the new state is not done or cancel, we should see the Edit link in last column of current row, after other links.

```
  $(".state-select-container").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var state = $(this).val();
            var url = "/MyController/ChangeState?requestId=" + id + "&state=" + state;
            var that = $(this);

            $.post(url, function (data) {
                if (data.updated) {
                  //some other codes
                    if (state !== 'Cancel' && state !== 'Done') { //Edit is authorized
                        var href = '/MyController/Edit?requestId='+ id +'"';

  //WHAT IS THE CORRECT CODE HERE? THE CODE, BELOW,
  //ADDS THE LINK AFTER THE CURRENT ROW, NOT IN LAST COLUMN, AFTER LAST SPAN

                        that.closest("tr").last('td').last('span')
                            .after('<a href="'+href+'">Edit</a>');
                     }

                } else {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
             });
        });
```

and the `.cshtml` is:

```
 <table>
 foreach (var item in ViewBag.SearchResult)
 {
 <tr>
   <td>
     <div>
       <select class="state-select-container" data-id="@item.Id">
          @{
             foreach (var state in states)
             {
               <option value="@state.Value"
                  @(item.State[0].ToString()==state.Value ?"selected":"")>
                        @state.Text
               </option>
              }
           }
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <span>
         <a data-id="@item.Id" href='its href' data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
      </span>
       @if (item.IsEditAuthorized)
         {
          <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "MyController", new {requestId = @item.Id}, null)'>Edit</a>
          }
     </td>

    </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

Comment: that.closest("tr").find('td:last-child').find('span:last-child')
                            .after('<a href="'+href+'">Edit</a>');

Comment: i did .can you check it below @Elnaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
that.closest("tr").find('td:last-child').find('span:last-chi‌​ld').after('<a href="'+href+'">Edit</a>');
```

[Read Documentation last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/)

> Note : last() This method does not accept any arguments.

Comment: thanks, what is wrong with the used code? we can not use .last().last()?

Answer (score 0):

Your js code seems ok, but your HTML code is ba, perhaps you close the first anchor tag:

```
<a data-id="@item.Id" href='its href' data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
```

EDIT:

Ok, the html code is ok, but last() jquery function doesn't accept arguments (https://api.jquery.com/last/). So the comment of JYoThI is correct, or using last function: 
    $(this).closest("tr").find('td').last().find('span').last()

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    that.closest("tr").last().append('<a href="'+href+'">Edit</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try,

```
that.closest("tr").children('td:last').children('span:last').after('<a href="'+href+'">Edit</a>');
```